# How to call super method?

Tags: swift, inheritance, overriding

```
class Subclass : Superclass {
    override func method() { /* ... */ }
}

let instance = Subclass()
instance.method() // I want to call Superclass.method() not Subclass.method()
```

Given this scenario how can I call Superclass.method() ?

Comment: What you are asking doesn't make any sense. You have two options 1) don't override your method in your subclass. 2) you can just create another method in your subclass and call super.method from there

Comment: What if Subclass is not mine?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not mine" but have you tried extending your Subclass `extension Subclass {
    func superMethod() {
        super.method()
    }
}` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. When you use the `override` keyword you tell the compiler to allow changing an inherited method in your subclass. This means that the subclass instances will have no knowledge about the implementation of the overriden superclass method.

Even if you cast a `Subclass` instance to `Superclass`, the actual type of the instance will still be `Subclass`, so if you do `(instance as Superclass).method()` it will still execute the overriden method.

If you want to be able to call the superclass implementation from your `Subclass` instances, you'll need to create another function for `Subclass` rather than overriding `method` from `Superclass`.

Comment: Would this work?  func superMethod() { super.method() }

Comment: @andrewz yes thats what I suggested